# How to add image to background a cell in table in another table html email template

Tags: html, html-email

I have a table, I already add an image as background of it. I use
https://backgrounds.cm/ to set image as backgourd in a cell. It work for outside table but inside table, it doesn't work, the image always in top of the outside table

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td background="img\source" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="821" height="462" valign="top">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:821px;height:462px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="img\source" color="#ffffff" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
              <![endif]-->
              <div>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                      <tr>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div align="center">
                  <table>
                      // I want to set another image as background of this table
                  </table>
              </div>
            

              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
              </v:rect>
              <![endif]-->
            </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Inside the table I have another table and I also want to add another image as background of it.
How can I do it?

Comment: Your image file is `img\source`  according to your code. Use a full URL for the image or use a Base64 URL (you can search the internet how that works). Please [complete the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do like that

```html
<td style="background: url('path/to/your/image.jpg') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
</td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).